# Need to sync backup Thunderbird IMAP folder to IMAP server

Tags: backup, thunderbird, imap, import

OS: Ubuntu 20.04
Thunderbird: 115.3.1(64 bit)
I reported a bug in the new updated version of Thunderbird. One of the troubleshooting steps was to install and test the latest beta version (119), which I did. When I went back to version 115, all my emails before that time were gone. I looked in every folder in Thunderbird available and they were nowhere to be found.
I logged into the webmail service for this account and it showed the same result.
I do nightly backups and copied my profile folder from backup to my local profile folder. When I start Thunderbird it shows all of emails from before the time I tested version 119. But once it syncs with the IMAP server the mailbox reverts to what is on the IMAP server.
How can I import what I have in my backup to the IMAP server? My host is Rackspace Email.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, when there is a conflict between the server and the client,
in email the server wins.

I think you'll need to export these old messages, turn on sync and
re-import the messages.

A tool I have used for export/import in Thunderbird is the
[ImportExportTools add-on](https://addons.thunderbird.net/en-US/thunderbird/addon/importexporttools/).

The tool adds an entry to the right-click context-menu of each mailbox.
You can then export and import messages from/to the mailbox.
Don't lose the profile backup, in case things go wrong.

Comment: Unfortunately, that addon is out of date :(

Comment: It's still working for me with Thunderbird.